# Can't get cookie queue to work in Laravel 4

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

This is what I have in my routes

```
Route::get('/track/{source}',function($source){
    Cookie::queue('source','XXXXXXXXXXXXXX',60);
    return View::make('items');
});
```

I go to `/track/123` in my browser and I see the correct page. However when I check `document.cookies` I don't see my cookie. Any idea what the issue might be?

Comment: Can you see your cookies in browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Laravel by default uses encrypted cookies. This means that while they are available by the client, they are pretty much unusable.

I ended up using flashdata for this.